# How to interpret the Normal distribution notation

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, multivariate-distribution

I know that the Normal distribution notation $N(0, 1)$ means that it has 0 mean and variance 1 but what does the following notation mean?

$N_{10} (0, I_{10})$

Comment: Most people would rely on context to figure this one out, because neither "$N_{10}$" nor "$I_{10}$" have universal, standard, or even commonly known meanings.  Where did you read this notation and what, if anything, did the author write beforehand in the way of definitions or explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X \sim N_{10}(0, I_{10})$ means that the random variable $X$ has a multivariate normal distribution with mean *vector* 0 and covariance matrix as the $10 \times 10$ identity matrix. Since the covariance matrix is identity, this can also be understood as

$X = (X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{10})$ where each $X_i \sim N(0, 1)$.